# When using AxWebBrowser which version of ie?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, axwebbrowser

I am using AxWebBrowser inside my app. How do I know which version of IE that is being used and how do I set it to ie 10?

Comment: I think there is generally only one version of IE installed at a time, so you might be forced to use whatever is installed?

Comment: What??? You don't "set" the version of IE. What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: The WPF webbrowser control defaults to IE 8 emulation and you change that in the registry. I was wondering about the AXWebBrowser control in a winforms app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to set/check the document mode in web browser control. You can try to set the default document mode by using [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation), and check the document mode by **documentMode** property of **IHTMLDocument6**.